# Automatic delete Cloud Logging logs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I would like to know if there is a way to periodically delete logs from inside `Cloud Logging`.

I have setup Firebase with `Cloud Functions` and i have an automatic `Cloud Logging` logs injection done for each function call.
I don't want especially to stop sending logs to `Cloud Logging`, but i would like to be able to manage my costs by deleting older logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a [retention policy](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods) on your Cloud Logging bucket to match with your requirements, which can auto-delete logs after between 1 day and 10 years.

Comment: Thanks Frank exactly what i was looking for.